# python import is not working in sibling directories

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, import

```
    bot
    ├── README.md
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── Login
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── Auth_con.py
    │   └── TFA.py
    ├── Study
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── Header.py
    └── utili
        ├─ __init__.py
        └── SS_log.py
```

I am currently testing a system and wanted to import TFA.py into Header.py

The TFA.py imports SS_log.py and Auth_con.py in order to perform a set of actions.
Now when I import TFA into the header file I get the following error,

```
    File "w:\Code\Automation\automation_StudyGen\Login\TFA.py", line 9, in <module>
     import Authenticator_connection
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Authenticator_connection
```

I have tried multiple approaches:

1. ```
    import os, sys
    sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
   ```
2. used relative paths as well as absolute paths
3. ```
   from Login import TFA
   from Login import Auth_con 
   from utili import SS_logs
   ```

   These are the imports in the header file
4. i have made an init file in all sub directories
5. sibling imports are working for SS_log (from utilis) and TFA (from login), but not for the stated case.
6. restarted kernal multiple times

Comment: python will not allow for this (at least natively) as it would expose code to circular references if it did.